# Grails & Spring Security - specialize User-Role based on additional property

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to configure my Grails 3 application with Spring Security 3 plugin to prevent users without specific permissions to access a set of specific features.
I used the default setup, with `User`, `Role` and `UserRole` domain classes (the latter included below), with the intention of making extensive use of `@Secure` or `@PreAuthorize` annotations.

Later, a new requirement came up: another domain class is `Project` (basically you can be granted access to one or more projects), and users might have project-specific permissions.

Example:

- there are **A**, **B**, **C** as `Roles`
- *User1* has **A** and **C** roles
- for *ProjectAlpha*, I want to "override" *User1*'s "default" roles so that he has **A** and **B** privileges.

So *User1*'s "real" permissions for a *ProjectAlpha* would have to be found among `UserRole` entries with that `Project` reference.

As first thing I was about to add a new `Project project` property for `UserRole` class, with `project` being pre-calculated in an interceptor. But then I cannot figure out the best approach (or even the feasibility) for this task.

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks in advance!

```
package myApp

import grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria
import groovy.transform.ToString

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder

@ToString(cache=true, includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class UserRole implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    static constraints = {
        role validator: { Role r, UserRole ur ->
            if(ur.user == null || ur.user.id == null) return
            boolean existing = false
            UserRole.withNewSession {
                existing = UserRole.exists(ur.user.id, r.id)
            }
            if(existing) {
                return 'userRole.exists'
            }
        }
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['user', 'role']
        version false
    }

    User user
    Role role

    /*UserRole(User u, Role r) {
        this()
        user = u
        role = r
    }*/

    @Override
    boolean equals(other) {
        if(!(other instanceof UserRole)) {
            return false
        }

        other.user?.id == user?.id && other.role?.id == role?.id
    }

    @Override
    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        if(user) builder.append(user.id)
        if(role) builder.append(role.id)
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    static UserRole get(long userId, long roleId) {
        criteriaFor(userId, roleId).get()
    }

    static boolean exists(long userId, long roleId) {
        criteriaFor(userId, roleId).count()
    }

    private static DetachedCriteria criteriaFor(long userId, long roleId) {
        UserRole.where {
            user == User.load(userId) &&
            role == Role.load(roleId)
        }
    }

    static UserRole create(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
        def instance = new UserRole(user: user, role: role)
        instance.save(flush: flush, insert: true)
        instance
    }

    static boolean remove(User u, Role r, boolean flush = false) {
        if(u == null || r == null) return false

        int rowCount = UserRole.where { user == u && role == r }.deleteAll()

        if(flush) { UserRole.withSession { it.flush() } }

        rowCount
    }

    static void removeAll(User u, boolean flush = false) {
        if(u == null) return

        UserRole.where { user == u }.deleteAll()

        if(flush) { UserRole.withSession { it.flush() } }
    }

    static void removeAll(Role r, boolean flush = false) {
        if(r == null) return

        UserRole.where { role == r }.deleteAll()

        if(flush) { UserRole.withSession { it.flush() } }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need [the ACL plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-acl). It will let you configure permissions for individual domain class instances for different users. Roles should be more coarse-grained, but if you want to configure read/edit/delete/admin/etc. permissions, ACLs are a better fit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! After checking a bit more in detail, I understood ACL plugin lets you define ad-hoc access rules for domain classes and services, but for my convenience I'd rather keep this logic at controller level.
I guess I'll define something like `def action() { if(checkUserRole(user, allowedRoles)) { /* set 401 status */ return } /* stuff */ }`